# nib file not getting registered in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, xib

My very first attempt at nib based project , here are my steps and a nib area snapshot

[image: Nib area snapshot]

Current Error - `Thread 1: Exception: "invalid nib registered for identifier (Cell) - nib must contain exactly one top level object which must be a UITableViewCell instance"`

Step 1 - I create a nib file called HotelNib and add a `viewCotroller` , create a class called `HotelViewController: UIViewController`, attach it to the viewController

Step 2 - in the nib add a tableView to viewController, give it constraints

Step 3 - go to `SceneDelegate` and add below code as i do not want the storyboard to load , also remove the main from drop-down

```
guard let winScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: winScene)
        guard let homeController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("HotelNib", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? HotelViewController else { return }
        window?.rootViewController = homeController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Step 4 - i run the project, it runs well

Step 5 - add a `tableViewCell` in nib area, create a class called `ItemViewCell: UITableViewCell`

Step 6 - add  `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`, in HotelView Controller, add delegates and datasource by control + drag from tableView to viewcontroller

Step 7 - Create   `@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!` in `ItemViewCell`

Step 8 - My code in HotelViewController, i just cannot get over, error after error about nib not being not able to register , some one please guide here

```
class HotelViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var restaurantNames = ["Cafe Deadend", "Homei", "Teakha", "Cafe Loisl", "Petite Oyster", "For Kee Restaurant", "Po's Atelier", "Bourke Street Bakery", "Haigh's Chocolate", "Palomino Espresso", "Upstate", "Traif", "Graham Avenue Meats And Deli", "Waffle & Wolf", "Five Leaves", "Cafe Lore", "Confessional", "Barrafina", "Donostia", "Royal Oak", "CASK Pub and Kitchen"]
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        restaurantNames.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ItemViewCell
        cell.nameLabel.text = restaurantNames[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("right load")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "HotelNib", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell") //always fails here
        
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having multiple views in a single .xib file also causes this error. Creating the table view cell in their own separate .xib file will resolve this error.

Comment: that was awesome